# Is there a way to avoid hard coding with Mongoose?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, hardcode

Consider the following code, where 'Team' is a mongoose model.

```
var Team = mongoose.model( 'Team' );
Team.find({'GroupName':gname}, function (err, teams) {
   // Some code
}
```

How do I get rid of this hard coding where I hard code 'GroupName':gname during selection in mongo?

Comment: What hard coding? You realize the arguments are just a JavaScript object don't you? It's not really clear what you are asking here as that is not the best example of avoiding hard coding.

Comment: Suppose, I have a file named 'Team.js' where I define a mongoose model. Now, I have another file 'other.js' where I'd like to fetch a Team document from mongo db.

Solution A:
Now, if I mention 'GroupName' attribute of a model in the 'other.js' file, then it seems I am increasing the coupling.

Solution B:
I move all the fetching and updation code to the model itself or to  a DAO like file.

Typing in 'GroupName' every time I need to select it or update it doesn't feel right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach is to define [static methods](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#statics) on your model that expose a DAO interface that encapsulates these sort of details:

**Team.js**

```
teamSchema.statics.findByGroupName = function (gname, cb) {
    this.find({ GroupName: gname }, cb);
};
...
```

**Other.js**

```
Team.findByGroupName(gname, function (err, teams) {
   // Some code
});
```

Comment: Hi Johnny, I too personally am in favor of the same approach. Thanks for your response.

Comment: You might also want to go through [hibernate meta models](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html/metamodel.html). This seems like an elegant solution.